# Paddings is not working

Tags: html, css

Here is the code where padding-right and padding-bottom is 0 but padding-left and padding-top is getting space. How to make them 0?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container{
         width:800px; 
         text-align: center;
         height:600px;
         margin:0 auto;
         border:1px solid black;
         overflow: hidden;
         padding: 0px; 
        }
         li{
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            list-style: none;
         }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="1.jpg" width="800px" height="600px" ></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: are you using some sort of framework (bootstrap / foundation etc) ?

Comment: Thanks a lit Azeez. It worked.

Comment: @user3595028 invoke your web tools from any modern browser (usually `F12`) and you evaluate to see applied style declaration at the element level.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of padding and margin from . Just make them zero using below code in your css :

```
ul { padding:0px; margin:0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The space you are seeing is not from the `div` element.

It's probably from the margin/padding from either the `body` or the `ul` element.

Try something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this style to your ul

```
#container ul {
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
}
```

I think this will fix your issue. I have attached a sample code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            width: 800px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        
        li {
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        #container ul {
            -webkit-padding-start: 0;
            -webkit-margin-before: 0;
            -webkit-margin-after: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="1.jpg" width="800px" height="600px"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't be necessary.. those styles should be overridden by any declaration from any source against `ul`. like inline, style blocks, href files..

Comment: I just specified as mentioned in this example. Its known that this will be overridden by any external style sheets, In that case we need to increase the weight of the css by adding classes specifically.

Comment: you don't need to add classes.. the best way to prioritize a declaration is to specify it from a root element. `div > ul` overrides `ul {}` regardless of whether it was specified first. `body div > ul` overrides both..

Comment: Yes that what I meant, prioritizing the styles by making the styles mode specific to its bounded dive in this case its #container ul